# @Optional() @Host() throws "Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency!" Error

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

My Problem is, i got a Server generating Code which gets compiled in runtime. The code should mainly manage form data. Because the datastructure is not known
i need a component, which is able to communicate with its host (same Component).

When i am using @Optional() @Host() Decorator i still get a "Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency!" Error.

Is there a ways to fix this or other suggestion for a solution.

Edit: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3zjnog?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

This is what my compoment looks like.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, AfterViewInit, Optional, Host } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mycomponent',
  templateUrl: './data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data.component.css']
})

export class DataComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  host: any;
  @Input() data: any = null;

  constructor(
    @Optional() @Host() host: DataComponent
  ) {
    this.host = host;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    if (!this.data) {
      this.data = this.host.data;
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Try with @SkipSelf If you want to inject same component other than itself in dom tree

Comment: This seems to work out form. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you need to generate HTML on the server, generate all of it on the server and put it in [innerHTML] or host it on a different server and embed an iframe. What you are doing is not what Angular was made for.

As for the question, you don't need @Host(). Just use:

```
constructor(private host: ElementRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit() { this.host.nativeElement.focus(); } //with focus-trigger as example
```